# Can you run Batch Apex after a callout?

Tags: apex, batch, callout, future

I have a callout that is scheduled every hour to import data. Upon finishing the import, I would like to call a Bach Class that works with the imported data. Right now, I get an error saying `Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch or future method`

Is there a way/hack to run batch apex after a callout? Or is there another architecture I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest you check the API version of the class first.If its 26.0 and above salesforce now provides ability to call another batch inside the finish method .Note that you need to call the other batch inside the Finish method of the parent batch(First batch).Also don't try to call only the exceute method .

Comment: Also please post some code on how you are approaching this ?

Comment: @Mohith, I have this method inside a class `@Future(Callout=True)
   global static void call(String email){}`  Upon completion of this call, I would like to run Batch. I think you mistaken it the other way around (Running callout on Batch finish).

Comment: As far as i remember in asynchronous mode its not possible to run batch.Lets see if someone comes with a solution

Comment: How about [scheduling the job](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) to run in one minute instead of executing it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch Apex cannot be invoked from a @future method.

You can run a frequently scheduled Apex Class (say every 5-10 mins) that scans a table to check whether it should run.

When your data import finishes, you can set this data, which then indicates to the Batch Job (the next time it runs) that the data is available and it executes.

If the flag is not set, the start method does not populate a QueryLocator, and therefore no processing would occur in the Execute method.

The other alternative is to have a webservice method which can invoke batch apex. This will however need to be externally invoked and is probably more relevant to a data push rather than pull.